# Task Schedular - Start task after entering pin

Tags: windows-10, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler

I'm logged into my PC with my Microsoft account (*not a local account*).

I am greeted with a pin box which then logs me in after I enter the correct pin.

I was wondering what options in task scheduler do I need to use to run the task **after** I enter my password.

Comment: Is this normal for people to post questions and answer them instantly themselves? nicely put answer though

Comment: Yes, I've read that it's encouraged, I googled it anyway and that's what I read. There's an option when you post a Q to do a QnA style one. That's what I used here. Thanks. I came here looking a direct answer, figured it out myself and thought I'd share it.

Comment: oh nice, good to know for future case.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the following settings.

**My current OS build:** `Version: 1909`. *Some settings in prior versions may not exist*

1. Click the start button or press the window key and start typing `Task...` which should bring up `Task scheduler`.
2. Then follow these 11 images to set that up:

[image: Create a new folder - Optional]

[image: Enter the folders name]

[image: Creating a new task]

[image: General tab]

[image: Triggers tab - Step 1]

[image: Triggers tab - Step 2]

[image: Triggers tab - Step 3]

[image: Triggers tab - Step 4]

[image: Actions tab]

[image: Conditions tab]

[image: Settings tab]